# c++ macro sideeffect

Tags: c++, macros, side-effects

I don't understand why the result is going to be 36. Can somebody explain to me what is happening here and what the preprocessor does?

```
#include <iostream>
#define QUADRAT(x) ((x) * (x))

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double no = 4.0;
    double result = QUADRAT(++no);

    cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks alot :>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preprocessor will replace `QUADRAT(++no)` with `((++no) * (++no))` in that example.

That would increment `no` twice, if it weren't for the fact that there are no sequence points between the two increments, so you are actually causing undefined behaviour. Any output you see is valid because no one can tell what will happen.

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor is a basically a copy-and-paste engine.  Note that a macro is **not** a function; instead, it's expanded inline.  Consider what happens to your code when the macro is expanded.

Comment: I meant your answer Seth, but weirdly Stackoverflow told me it were Oli who posted it by mistake. Now your name is below it.. :/

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
double result = QUADRAT(++no);
```

gets expanded to this:

```
double result = ((++no) * (++no));
```

The way that this ends up running is equivalent to:

```
no = no + 1;
no = no + 1;
result = no * no;
```

It runs this way because the increments are performed before the multiplication: the preprocessor does a textual copy of what you pass it, so it copies the "++no" so that it shows up twice in the final code, and the increment of each ++no happens before the result is computed. The way to fix this is to use an inline function:

```
inline double QUADRAT(double x) { return x * x; }
```

Most modern compilers will expand this code out without doing a textual substitution - they'll give you something as fast as a preprocessor definition, but without the danger of having issues like the one you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is a sort of literal substitution of ++no in place of x, it is like you have written:

```
double result = ((++no) * (++no));
```

What is the result... it should be undefined behaviour (you get 36 by chance), and g++ with -Wall agrees with me.